# Conversion errors from Swift 3.0 to Swift 4.2 at SQLitt.Swift unregonized token

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2, sqlite.swift, xcode11.4

My current code is written with Swift 3 ,I tried to change Swift 4.2 via Xcode10.1. SQLite is crashing on changes version and working correct on old code.

I'm trying to retrieve a count of records in a table using SQLite.swift and Swift in a Cocoa macOS application.

```
let db = try Connection("\(pathh)/db.sqlite3")
let users = Table("users")
var count = try db.scalar(users.filter(userid == userid).count)
```

However, when this code is executed, the following exception is thrown:

```
unrecognized token: ":" (code: 1)
```

When I tried to use `var count = try db.scalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE userid=?",userid) as! Int64` , the correct result is returned.
But this usu-age return error

```
no such table tablename (code:1)
```

for some table.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In my project,I required updating was the following in my Podfile:

```
pod 'SQLCipher', '~>4.2.0'
pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLChiper', '~>0.12.0'
```

After pod update 
unrecognized token: ":" (code: 1) is solved.